# VueJS tab selection indicator moves on page load

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

Tab indicator moves little right when page reload for the first time or sometimes it covers all width, not selected as the second image

[image: On First load error]

sometimes it covers all width, not selected like this.

[image: On First load sometimes]

But it's working fine after clicking on any tab like the image below

[image: working after click any tab]

Comment: This is CSS issue. Can you please share your code ? (codepen or jsfiddle)

Comment: It's happening only when page first load, But it works well after clicking any tab.
here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/jahanbabu/ogetrf2w/

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Are you able to fix it ?  In data can you please set ntab:0.  like data() {return { ntab:0 };}

Comment: I have tried that, unfortunately, that didn't work. Not fixed yet.

Comment: Ok. If possible please comment/remove all your external css code/files. then try again. It's hard to tell where the problem without seeing the full code. you can create a simple new project and install vuetify  and test again. If possible you can share github repo. so i can test locally.

Comment: if non of those tricks work then create an issue https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues. maybe someone already face this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue by changing the v-tabs class from centered to fixed-tabs. Maybe the issue was in centered class because of the parent view also in the center.